# ¿Por qué no me crea el número de intervalos de clase que especifico?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, conda

Disponemos del siguiente DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

values_dict = {'Values(Xi)': {'2016-01-04': 9,
                             '2016-01-05': 15,
                             '2016-01-06': 64,
                             '2016-01-07': 28,
                             '2016-01-08': 89,
                             '2016-01-09': 93,
                             '2016-01-10': 29,
                             '2016-01-11': 8,
                             '2016-01-12': 73,
                             '2016-01-13': 0,
                             '2016-01-14': 40,
                             '2016-01-15': 36,
                             '2016-01-16': 16,
                             '2016-01-17': 11,
                             '2016-01-18': 54,
                             '2016-01-19': 88,
                             '2016-01-20': 62,
                             '2016-01-21': 33,
                             '2016-01-22': 72,
                             '2016-01-23': 78,
                             '2016-01-24': 49,
                             '2016-01-25': 51,
                             '2016-01-26': 54,
                             '2016-01-27': 77,
                             '2016-01-28': 69,
                             '2016-01-29': 13,
                             '2016-01-30': 25,
                             '2016-01-31': 13,
                             '2016-02-01': 92,
                             '2016-02-02': 86,
                             '2016-02-03': 30,
                             '2016-02-04': 30,
                             '2016-02-05': 89,
                             '2016-02-06': 12,
                             '2016-02-07': 65,
                             '2016-02-08': 31}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values_dict, orient='index').T.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'Date', 'Values(Xi)': 'Values(Xi)'})
df[['Values(Xi)']] = df[['Values(Xi)']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

En la columna df['Values(Xi)], tenemos los valores de una muestra de datos. Deseamos dividir el recorrido de esta serie de valores (diferencia entre el valor máximo y el mínimo), en en un número especificado de clases. Para ello hacemos.

```
# Cálcula las clases con 6 intervalos de clase

def estima_tamaño_intervalos(datos, intervals_number):
    # Recorrido de la variable
    variable_range = calcula_recorrido(datos)[2]
    lim_inf = float(datos.min())
    lim_sup = float(datos.max())

    """Tamaño de los intervalos""" 
    interval_size = math.ceil(variable_range / intervals_number)
    
    # Ajustar tamaño del último intervalo si es necesario
    last_interval_size = variable_range - (interval_size * (intervals_number - 1))
    if last_interval_size < interval_size:
        interval_size = last_interval_size
    
    return lim_inf, lim_sup, interval_size, variable_range 


def crea_intervalos(data, intervals_number):
    lim_inf, lim_sup, interval_size, variable_range = estima_tamaño_intervalos(data['Values(Xi)'],intervals_number)
    intervals = pd.interval_range(start=lim_inf, end=lim_sup, freq=interval_size, name="Intervalo", closed="left")
    
    df_clases = pd.DataFrame(index=intervals)
    df_clases["Fi"] = pd.cut(data['Values(Xi)'], bins=intervals, include_lowest=True)
    return df_clases

# utilizaremos sales_df obtenido en el apartado 1.1
data = df.copy(deep=True)
# Calcula el número de muestras                             
samples_number= calcula_numero_muestras(data)
# Calcula el ecorrido                             
maximo, minimo, recorrido = calcula_recorrido(data)

# Número de intervalos
intervals_number = 6

lim_inf, lim_sup, interval_size, variable_range  = estima_tamaño_intervalos(data, intervals_number )
df_clases = crea_intervalos(data, intervals_number)

df_clases
```

En lugar de las 6 clases esperadas, me devuelve 7.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Al calcular el tamaño de tu último intervalo estás ajustando el tamalo del intervalo, es decir, lo que tenías como tamaño producto de la división lo reduces, por lo tanto, ya no tienes un intervalo exacto que fue dividido en partes iguales sino uno menor donde entra una ocurrencia adicional, es decir, en ves de reducir el ultimo, reduces el de todos.

Comment: Parece como si, cuando variable_range se divide por intervals_number, el resultado puede no ser exacto, por lo que si intervals_number es redondeado hacia arriba, el número de intervalos resultantes será menor que intervals_number por 1. No sé si aún así todos los valores quedan incluidos en los intervalos resultantes. SI así fuera, para ver el error de agrupamiento me servirían estas funciones.